# Async Task gives AccesViolation on Wifi with UWP

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, uwp

I want to make a Wifimanager class for UWP (Raspberry pi 3)

I looked at some tutorials and figured i was good to go.
So I came up with this:

```
public class WifiManager
{
    private WiFiAdapter adapter;
    public List<WifiNetwork> Networks;
    public WifiManager()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private async void Initialize()
    {
        var access = await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();
        if (access != WiFiAccessStatus.Allowed)
        {
            throw new WifiAdaperAccessDeniedException();
        }
        else
        {
            var result = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(WiFiAdapter.GetDeviceSelector());
            if (result.Count >= 1)
            {
                adapter = await WiFiAdapter.FromIdAsync(result[0].Id);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NoWifiAdapterFoundException();
            }

        }
    }

    public async Task GetAvailableNetWorksAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            if (adapter != null)
            {
                await adapter.ScanAsync();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw new WifiAdaperAccessDeniedException();
        }

        Networks = new List<WifiNetwork>();
        foreach(var network in adapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks)
        {
            Networks.Add(new WifiNetwork(network, adapter));
        }

    }
}
```

However when I try to get the Available Networks using the async function the adapter is null. When I remove the if statement around `await adapter.ScanAsync();` I get an AccessViolation.

I dont have much experience with async tasks and such, but the tutorials i found did not gave me the explaination i needed to fix this.

Comment: Having never worked with UWP, can you watch your code with a debugger?  It looks like you might be running the `foreach(var network in adapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks)` code on your adapter object without initializing it.  Try moving that foreach into the if statement you are focused on.  I would also move the Networks list object initialization to the Initialize method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling an async method from the constructor. Since you do no wait for the result and are probably calling `GetAvailableNetWorksAsync` directly after the constructor the `adapter` variable has not been set yet..

You need to take it out of the constructor like this:

```
public class WifiManager
{
    private WiFiAdapter adapter;
    public List<WifiNetwork> Networks;

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        var access = await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();
        if (access != WiFiAccessStatus.Allowed)
        {
            throw new WifiAdaperAccessDeniedException();
        }
        else
        {
            var result = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(WiFiAdapter.GetDeviceSelector());
            if (result.Count >= 1)
            {
                adapter = await WiFiAdapter.FromIdAsync(result[0].Id);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NoWifiAdapterFoundException();
            }

        }
    }

    public async Task GetAvailableNetWorksAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            if (adapter != null)
            {
                await adapter.ScanAsync();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw new WifiAdaperAccessDeniedException();
        }

        Networks = new List<WifiNetwork>();
        foreach(var network in adapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks)
        {
            Networks.Add(new WifiNetwork(network, adapter));
        }

    }
}
```

Now your calling code probably looks like this:

```
var wifiManager = new WifiManager();
await wifiManager.GetAvailableNetWorksAsync();
```

change that to

```
var wifiManager = new WifiManager();
await wifiManager.InitializeAsync();
await wifiManager.GetAvailableNetWorksAsync();
```

**Take away:** do not call async methods in a constructor since you cannot await completion using the `await` keyword and using `.Wait()` or `.Result` might give other troubles . Applies for 99% of all situations.

Another approach could be something like:

```
public class WifiManager
{
    private WiFiAdapter adapter;
    public List<WifiNetwork> Networks;

    pivate async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        var access = await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();
        if (access != WiFiAccessStatus.Allowed)
        {
            throw new WifiAdaperAccessDeniedException();
        }
        else
        {
            var result = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(WiFiAdapter.GetDeviceSelector());
            if (result.Count >= 1)
            {
                adapter = await WiFiAdapter.FromIdAsync(result[0].Id);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NoWifiAdapterFoundException();
            }

        }
    }

    public async Task GetAvailableNetWorksAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            if (adapter == null)
            {
                await InitializeAsync();
            }

            if (adapter != null)
            {
                await adapter.ScanAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw new WifiAdaperAccessDeniedException();
        }

        Networks = new List<WifiNetwork>();
        foreach(var network in adapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks)
        {
            Networks.Add(new WifiNetwork(network, adapter));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between async void and async task?

Comment: you can only wait for the result of an async method if it returns a `Task` or `Task<T>`. A void cannot be awaited. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx and http://theburningmonk.com/2012/10/c-beware-of-async-void-in-your-code/. So what happens that your code in the `Initialize` is still running in the background while the rest of the application could already be running the code in `GetAvailableNetWorksAsync`

Comment: @RoXaS I also recommend this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx#What Happens in an Async Method as it shows the flow.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly and thanks for your explaination :D